# How to obtain a S/MIME certificate for e-mail encryption?

Tags: thunderbird, encryption, email, pgp, openpgp

There are parties, e.g. enterprises, that uses S/MIME certificates for e-mail encryption. To my understanding Thunderbird has support by default for S/MIME. But I have not found a way to obtain a personal S/MIME certificate to be used on a Ubuntu system. Thus my question:

*How to obtain a S/MIME certificate for e-mail encryption?*

Moreover, is it correct to believe that Thunderbird has support by default for S/MIME?

I am fully aware of PGP, GnuPG and OpenPGP for public-key cryptography and secure e-mail communication. In my opinion, it is very useful that OpenPGP is installed by default on Ubuntu systems. But I need to find a method to communicate securely with parties that use S/MIME and not PGP/GnuPG/OpenPGP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some issuing bodies that will give you a free certificate, as listed [in this Mozillazine article here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Getting_an_SMIME_certificate). One company that offers them for no charge is [Comodo](https://secure.comodo.com/products/frontpage?area=SecureEmailCertificate) and another is *startssl* as mentioned by Taneli, so those two are two decent possibilities. Personally, I used the Comodo certificate for a while until I had to move to OpenPGP. The Comodo one is guaranteed to work with `s/mime` compliant applications and their [information page](https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/free-email-certificate.html) mentions `thunderbird`.

`Thunderbird` by default has great support for `S/MIME` signing and encryption. As noted [in another mozillazine article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_FAQs_:_Install_an_SMIME_Certificate), it is relatively quick to setup, although it is advised to set a [master password](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Master_password) as well to protect the use of your certificates. Importantly, you need to do this before importing your certificate into `thunderbird`.

- You need to import your certificate into `thunderbird` by going to edit > preferences > advanced > certificates (first screenshot).
- You then need to add your certificate to your `Thunderbird` mail account (see second screenshot) by going to account settings and clicking the security tab. All this is simple to setup and to use once you have your certificate.
- The security options are clearly visible when composing a mail (see third screenshot) and you can add your signature or fully encrypt the mail.

These screenshots are from `thunderbird` 14.
(Note: I have temporarily removed the `enigmail` OpenPGP addon from my copy of `thunderbird` so that the menus in my screenshots should look the same as in your `thunderbird`.)

[image]
  [image]
  [image]

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience using them in thunderbird, but S/MIME certificates are issued by certificate authorities. This often involves some sort of payment and validation (of sorts) of your identity / existence. For practical purposes, at least [startSSL](http://www.startssl.com/?app=1) seems to be issuing them for free. Many organizations (companies, schools, etc) may be able to issue such certificates for their employees/other associates.

Comment: As an updated for this comment that was posted back in 2017, as of January 1st, 2018, StartSSL "does not issue any new certificate from StartCom name roots"[\[1\]](https://archive.is/96HUk).